# Strong convergence from elliptic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider the following equation

$$ \Delta A_n = -2\Im(\bar{u}_n(\nabla -iA_n)u_n) =: -J(u_n,A_n)$$

and suppose that $u_n \in L^{\infty}(I,H^1(\Omega))$ for some bounded $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose that $\partial_t u_n \in L^{\infty}(I,H^{-1}(\Omega))$ such that by Aubin-Lions we have strong convergence to $u$ in, say $L^4(I\times \Omega)$ (it works for every $L^p(I,L^q(\Omega))$ for $p\in [1,\infty]$ and $q\in [2,6)$ by Rellich-Kondrachov). I want to deduce some strong convergence for $A_n$ using the equation above. So I know that $\|u_n-u\|_{L^4(I\times \Omega)} \rightarrow 0$. **Can I deduce that $\|A_n-A\| \rightarrow 0$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$?**

I tried:

$$\|A_n-A\|_6 \leq \|J_n-J\|_{6/5} \\\leq \|u_n\|_3 \|\nabla u_n- \nabla u \|_2 + \|u_n-u\|_3\|\nabla u\|_2 \\
+\|A_n\|_6 \||u_n|^2-|u|^2\|_{3/2} + \|A_n-A\|_6 \|u\|_3^2 \\
\lesssim \|u_n\|_{H^1}(\|\nabla u_n- \nabla u \|_2 + \||u_n|^2-|u|^2\|_{3/2}) \\
+\|u\|_{H^1}(\|u\|_{H^1}\|A-A_n\|_6 + \|u_n-u||_3)$$
where I used $\|A_n\|_6 \lesssim \|u\|_{H^1}$ which one obtains through the equation $\Delta A = -J(u,A)$ above (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377772/estimates-for-an-elliptic-pde)) and Sobolev embedding. However now I have $\|A-A_n\|_6$ on both sides so that doesn't really help me.

Next thing I tried was substracting $\Delta A = -J_n$ from $\Delta A_n = -J$, multiplying by $A_n-A$ and integrating to obtain

$$\|\nabla A_n - \nabla A\|_2^2 \simeq \int (\bar{u}\nabla u - \bar{u}_n \nabla u_n)(A_n-A)dx + \int (A|u|^2-A_n|u_n|^2)(A_n-A)dx, $$

but I'm stuck here as well. Feel free to ask for clarifications.